# Unattended installation of Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, deployment

I'm about to deploy Windows 8 on like 50 desktops, did basic testing using virtualization, but there is a problem with the Unattend.xml file that I can't figure out. It's not loading, client acts as if it's not there, and the Windows Deployment Services UI pops up.

Unattend.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
   <settings pass="windowsPE">
      <component name="Microsoft Windows Setup (x86)" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="x86">
         <WindowsDeploymentServices>
            <Login>
               <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
               <Credentials>
                     <Username>user</Username>
                     <Domain>domain</Domain>
                     <Password>pass</Password>
                  </Credentials>
               </Login>
            <ImageSelection>
               <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
               <InstallImage>
                  <ImageName>Windows 8</ImageName>
                  <ImageGroup>OSImageGroup</ImageGroup>
                  <Filename>Install.wim</Filename>
               </InstallImage>
                  <InstallTo>
                  <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                  <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
               </InstallTo>
            </ImageSelection>
         </WindowsDeploymentServices>
         <DiskConfiguration>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
               <Disk>
                  <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                  <WillWipeDisk>false</WillWipeDisk>
                  <ModifyPartitions>
                     <ModifyPartition>
                        <Order>1</Order>
                        <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                        <Letter>C</Letter>
                        <Label>TestOS</Label>
                        <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        <Active>true</Active>
                        <Extend>false</Extend>
                     </ModifyPartition>
                  </ModifyPartitions>
            </Disk>
         </DiskConfiguration>
      </component>
      <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" processorArchitecture="x86">
         <SetupUILanguage>
            <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
         </SetupUILanguage>
         <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
      </component>
   </settings>
</unattend>
```

Comment: this question might be better suited for ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: what are you using? MDT?

Comment: yes MDT, i configure the answer file in WDS server, never mind its no longer my problem...